# Change the Windows 8 product key after installation?

Tags: windows-activation, windows-installation, windows-8, product-key

I just completed a fresh install of Windows 8 Pro as it was released to MSDN. Installation went without a hitch however I can't find out where to enter the correct product key for the copy I have.

Clicking on the Activate this Computer in Activity Centre displays the following screen, but no option to change the product key:

[image: Windows 8 Activation Screen]

Comment: Have you checked out this [link](http://blogs.objectsharp.com/blogs/max/archive/2012/08/16/change-windows-8-product-key-after-install.aspx).

Comment: @avirk Please post a detailed answer including that link and I will accept the answer.

Comment: Diago as you said Done! :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just follow these steps to add/change product key using Command Prompt and `slmgr.vbs`:

1. Launch Command Prompt as an **Administrator**.
2. At the command prompt, type in `slmgr.vbs -ipk`*`(insert your product key here)`* and click <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. To activate windows, type in `slmgr.vbs -ato` and click <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

All information form this [Source](http://blogs.objectsharp.com/blogs/max/archive/2012/08/16/change-windows-8-product-key-after-install.aspx)

Answer (score 12):

The command to display the GUI for changing the product key is `slui 3` (you need to run the cmd.exe as an administrator).

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. I edited your answer, please refrain from posting rants and such, please check the FAQ, too. Feel free to edit your question again if you want to add something.

Comment: That's a much more convenient way to do this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also go to `System` (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>) and click the "Change product key" link at the bottom. This works in both Windows 7 and 8.