# Can I install Windows 8 from MSDN now and switch to my own license when they are available for purchase?

Tags: windows-8, windows-installation

I have a computer at home with valid a Windows 7 license and I have MSDN access at work.  Can I install Windows 8 on this home machine now from MSDN and then when they are available switch that install over to one of the cheap upgrade licenses that I purchase personally without having to reinstall?

Comment: Are you allowed to use these MSDN licenses for personal use? You would have to change the authentication key for Windows. Only certain versions of Windows have a supported method to change the authentication key. Technically licenses from a MSDN subscription should only be used to develop software.  Besides this question has been asked and answered, it might have been for a previous version, but the answer remains the same.

Comment: I did look to see if this question was asked.  It is not the same question for previous versions as they typically have different license restrictions.  If you are going to dink me would you at least let me know what question I duplicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure not. The versions of Windows 8 from MSDN do not allow you to "downgrade" to a home license. You're better off sticking with Windows 7 until Windows 8 comes out in retail settings. That's not even mentioning the legalities of if you're allowed to install Windows 8 on your personal computer with a corporate MSDN account(if you're not developing software at home?)

Comment: *> if you're not developing software at home?*   What programmer doesn’t do at least *some* work at home?

Comment: @Synetech true. I was just saying. I'm really not for sure what MSDN's licenses are

Comment: Windows 8 Pro is available on MSDN, which is what I will purchasing an upgrade license to.  My understanding is that it is valid to install MSDN software at home if you are using it in the performance of your work duties.  At any rate I am not seeking to get free software, just to get access a month before I am allowed to pay for it.

Comment: @MatthewNichols then this might work: http://superuser.com/questions/463208/change-the-windows-8-product-key-after-installation

Comment: @Earlz It was a duplicate after all. My bad and thanks for pointing it out.