# How do I deactivate windows 8 pro?

Tags: windows-8, windows-activation

I would like to deactivate the copy of Windows 8 Pro that I have installed on my system because one of cousins attempted on Install windows from the same disk and activated with same key. So, I would like to buy a new product for it. Do I need reinstall it over again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the Windows 8 product key after installation?](http://superuser.com/questions/463208/change-the-windows-8-product-key-after-installation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the Windows 8 product key after installation?](https://superuser.com/questions/463208/change-the-windows-8-product-key-after-installation)

Answer (score 8):

Press the <kbd>[image: Win]</kbd> key, then type `Run` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Type `slmgr.vbs -upk`, and click <kbd>OK</kbd>

It should deactivate the license and get you into trial, from there you can reactivate using another license

Answer (score -1):

1. Windows Key
2. (Focus is in Search field) Type cmd
3. (Your search result is returned) Right Click Command Prompt
4. (Contextual menu open) Click Run as Administrator
5. slmgr /dlv
6. Copy the ActivationID to notepad or something
7. slmgr /upk ActivationID (FROM STEP 6)

Comment: I got a negative. Can anyone tell me WHY?